# Problem trying to install Ubuntu on Asus ZX50V notebook PC with Nvidia GTX 960M

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, nouveau

OK, I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a friend's Asus ZX50V (ZX50VW-MS71) notebook PC. After entering the boot menu and selecting the Ubuntu install media the installation freezes at the loading screen (the screen with the Ubuntu logo and 5 dots). It just stays there forever. The same thing when trying to install elementary OS. It just freezes at the elementary logo (e). Problem is its not showing any errors or whatsoever.

Then I tried installing deepin OS. There I can clearly see an error. It's something related to 'nouveau'. I'm currently burning the deepin ISO to a USB disk to get the exact error. Based on my research, nouveau is related to Nvidia. But I don't understand why the Linux installations are failing.

[Here is a pic of the error when trying to install deepin OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jRVY.jpg)

What's causing this? Any fixes?

Tamrat

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Comment: @PJSingh I tried both 16.04 and 18.04. They both freeze at the same point: the loading screen. I have added a photo of the error when trying to install deepin OS

Comment: This is a shot in the dark,... but try adding `vga=795` to your boot options. (See the section "Changing the CD Boot Option Configuration Line" at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions).  You might also try adding the `acpi=off` boot option. Note: other possible values for `vga` are at https://www.pendrivelinux.com/vga-boot-modes-to-set-screen-resolution/.

Comment: Okay, interestingly `nomodeset` option from the GRUB menu fixed the problem and now I have installed Ubuntu 18.04. The only problem now is it always boots to black screen . Trying to fix that.

Comment: Great. I figured you might find one the other boot options that would work for you. Search for posts about Nvidia cards and  blank screen for your second question. Good luck!

Comment: After a lot of research and a lot of attempts to install drivers, we gave up on it. The PC just won't boot into Linux without the `nomodeset` option. And this makes the resolution locked to 800x600 which is absolutely terrible.